# TemplateNotFound when installing CKAN python extension

Tags: python, jinja2, ckan

I tried to install ckanext-archiver plugin for CKAN following the steps described in [GIT page](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-archiver).

However, when I restart the web server, the following error occurs.

I tried using both '*pip install*' and '*python setup.py install/develop*' directly from git, downloading the zip, cloning the code in my machine.

The error is always the same when I refresh the server:

```
Source Template Extra Data Traceback
WebError Traceback:
⇝ TemplateNotFound: package\resource_read.html

Module ckan.controllers.package:1142 in resource_read 
>>  return render(template, extra_vars=vars)
Module ckan.lib.base:216 in render
>>  loader_class=loader_class)
Module pylons.templating:249 in cached_template
>>  return render_func()
Module ckan.lib.base:154 in render_template
>>  return render_jinja2(template_name, globs)
Module ckan.lib.base:104 in render_jinja2
>>  return template.render(**extra_vars)
Module jinja2.environment:894 in render
>>  return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
Module c:\users\bp\envs\ckan2.5.2env\src\ckanext-archiver\ckanext\archiver\templates\package\resource_read.html:1 in top-level template 
>>  {% ckan_extends %}
Module ckan.lib.jinja_extensions:182 in get_source
>>  pieces = loaders.split_template_path(template)
Module jinja2.loaders:33 in split_template_path
>>  raise TemplateNotFound(template)
TemplateNotFound: package\resource_read.html
```

I'm using CKAN 2.5.2 installed on Windows 8 and I managed to install other extensions.

The referred page does exist in the path and it has the folowing content:

```
{% ckan_extends %}

{% block resource_additional_information_inner %}
    {# This is copied from core ckan, but with the changes marked #}
        <div class="module-content">
          <h2>{{ _('Additional Information') }}</h2>
          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" data-module="table-toggle-more">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">{{ _('Field') }}</th>
                <th scope="col">{{ _('Value') }}</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{ _('Last updated') }}</th>
                <td>{{ h.render_datetime(res.last_modified) or h.render_datetime(res.revision_timestamp) or h.render_datetime(res.created) or _('unknown') }}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{ _('Created') }}</th>
                <td>{{ h.render_datetime(res.created) or _('unknown') }}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{ _('Format') }}</th>
                <td>{{ res.mimetype_inner or res.mimetype or res.format or _('unknown') }}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{ _('License') }}</th>
                <td>{% snippet "snippets/license.html", pkg_dict=pkg, text_only=True %}</td>
              </tr>
              {# We replaced h.format_resource_items with h.archiver_format_resource_items so that we can hide the archiver key #}
              {% for key, value in h.archiver_format_resource_items(res.items()) %}
                <tr class="toggle-more"><th scope="row">{{ key }}</th><td>{{ value }}</td></tr>
              {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>

  {{ h.archiver_is_resource_broken_html(c.resource) }}<br>
  {{ h.archiver_is_resource_cached_html(c.resource) }}

{% endblock %}
```

Can anyone point me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like a Windows thing - so I don't know. Maybe put a breakpoint into the jinja code and debug what absolute path it's trying to access?

Comment: Thanks for yout input, @D-Read. In fact, I think that Windows treats path characters differently from Ubuntu. I had to change the file \jinja2\loaders.py to consider backslashes and it worked for me with all other packages.

    #for piece in template.split('/'):
    template = template.replace('/', '\\')
    for piece in template.split('\\'):